# How to run python script with Azure Data Factory using files on a VM?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have a VM that contains files that I run a python script against.  How could I make a data factory pipeline on my local machine that connects to the VM and runs the python script?

I have looked into using a custom batch activity, but I'm not sure how this can connect to the VM.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can Upload the **python script** into **Azure blob storage** , First connect Blob storage to **[VM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/private-link/tutorial-private-endpoint-storage-portal)** and also we can use  **[AzCopy](https://www.sqlshack.com/use-azcopy-to-upload-data-to-azure-blob-storage/)**  to upload files into Azure Blob Storage.

Follow these steps for **Custom batch activity** and use Below **Reference** in which we have detailed information about:

1. Create the Azure Batch Account
2. Create the Azure Pool.  You can follow this link for  Azure Pool creation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/batch/quick-create-portal
3. Upload the python script in the Azure blob storage
4. Add the custom activity in the Azure Data factory Pipeline and configure to use the Azure batch pool and run the python script Default output of any **batch activity** is stored in storage account under **output/stdout.txt** and if any program failure happens, it will get stored in **output/stderr.txt**

**Reference:**

https://azurelib.com/custom-activity-azure-data-factory/

https://medium.com/@ashish.kats/custom-batch-activity-in-azure-data-factory-110d8c1c957b